# Xamarin Forms check is page is Modal

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm

So basically I'm try to to find out if a page was pushed modally.

Here is the code I have for my extension method:

```
public static bool IsModal(this Page page)
{
    return page.Navigation.ModalStack.Any(p => page == p);
}
```

The issue is; `p` never equals `page` due to the fact `p` changes to NavigationPage during runtime although intellisense reports it as a type of Page at compile time.

I've tried casting `p` to a Page but the type does not change at runtime and intellisense just moans that the cast is redundant.

I call this extension by using `CurrentPage.IsModal` in my View Model. `CurrentPage` is a type of Page at compile time but then changes to NavigationPage at runtime.

The confusing thing is that during debugging, `p` has properties such as `CurrentPage` and `RootPage` which show in the debugger, but these are not accessible by using `p.CurrentPage` as the compiler complains they don't exist !?! I was going to try an compare these but I can't access them but can view them in the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the type of page first, a page without navigationbar can also be pushed modally:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void  Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page1 p = new Page1();

        await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(p, true);

        bool b = PageExtensions.IsModal(p);

        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}

public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static bool IsModal(this Page page)
    {
        if (page.GetType() == typeof(NavigationPage))
        {
            return page.Navigation.ModalStack.Any(p => ((NavigationPage)p).CurrentPage.Equals(page));
        }
        else
        {
            return page.Navigation.ModalStack.Any(p => p.Equals(page));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jack, I've marked this as the answer even though its very similar to mine. It adds more clarity for type checking the page as I found out the cast can fail.

Comment: Nice solution. I've noticed that, at least in Maui, if you are testing within the page, for example 
if (this.IsModal ()) {...},
it does not work in a constructor but does work in OnAppearing ().

Answer (score 1):

So this code works:

```
public static class PageExtensions
{
    public static bool IsModal(this Page page)
    {
        return page.Navigation.ModalStack.Any(p=> ((NavigationPage) p).CurrentPage.Equals(page));
    }
}
```

I'm concerned that is not safe as it assumes `p` is a Type of NavigationPage.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, there could be typos, I wrote this freehand

```
public static bool IsModal(this Page page)
        {
            if (page.Navigation.ModalStack.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var thisPage in page.Navigation.ModalStack)
                {
                    if (thisPage.Equals(page))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
```

Comment: Your syntax is correct, but the comparison still fails. I've tried code similar to this and using either the == or equals comparer, they both fail.

Comment: Its got to do with when page.Navigation.ModalStack is iterated, the type is NavigationPage and not Page. Simply casting does not work as the compiler thinks at runtime the page is already Page.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I made to check the last pushed modal. Hope it helps to someone.

```
public async Task NewModalPagePushAsync(Page pageToOpen)
{
    var lastModalPage = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack;

     if (lastModalPage.Count >= 1)
     {
        if (lastModalPage.Last().GetType().Name == pageToOpen.GetType().Name)
        return;
     }
     await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(pageToOpen);
}
```